# Triple integration on a set, find integration extreme

Tags: integration

I have this problem, evaluate this integral:

$$\iiint\limits_T\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$$ $$T=\{x\gt 0,y\gt 0,z\gt 0, x+y+z\lt 2\}$$

So saw the figure and I tried to solve it as follows:

$$\int_0^2\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x-y}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz=0$$

But I think I failed to set the extreme of the integration, because the result of the integral is wrong. Can you tell where is the mistake?
Where am I failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that when z=0

[image]

$0 \le x \le 2$ and $0 \le y \le 2-x  $ and z is correct $0 \le z \le 2-x-y$

Answer (score 1):

In this case, we have
$$V=\iiint\limits_T\mathrm dV$$
Now let's define region $T$ as
$$\{(x,y,z):(x,y)\in D, 0\leq z\leq 2-x-y\}$$
Which yields the following bounds for each variable
$$0\leq z\leq 2-x-y$$
$$0\leq y\leq 2-x$$
$$0\leq x\leq 2$$
So now we have
$$\iint\limits_D\left(\int_0^{2-x-y}\mathrm dz\right)\mathrm dA$$
$$=\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}\int_0^{2-x-y}\mathrm dz\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$$
$$=\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}(2-x-y)\ \mathrm dy\mathrm dx$$
$$=\frac12\int_0^2 (2-x)^2\ \mathrm dx$$
$$=\frac12\int_0^2 u^2\ \mathrm du$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: yes, but i know the result is $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: @Mazzorca, the result is indeed $\frac43$ as shown above. Can you update your question and show how you got $\frac23$?

Comment: This is a problem of a univerity test, i know only the result but not the method. I try with the method showed in the question, but don't work, and your method, seem correct.

Comment: @Mazzorca Perhaps the original problem was$$\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}\int_0^{2-x-y}x\ \mathrm dz\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$$ Which is in fact, equivalent to $\frac23$. I'll update my answer if this is the case. Please confirm.